# Index of specific instance in swift array/collection

Tags: arrays, swift, memory, collections

I have the following code in my playground:

```
let array = [3,3]
let first = array.first!
let last = array.last!

let indices = [array.index(of: first)!, array.index(of: last)!]
print(indices) // This prints [0,0]
```

I understand that the "index(of:)" method just grabs the first matching instance from the array, which is more efficient, but I'm wondering if there is a way to grab that last index based on the fact that I have gotten the value from "array.last".

Additionally, if I had the following:

```
let lotsOfThrees = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
let fourthThree = lotsOfThrees[3]
// Write code to return the index of "fourthThree" (possibly based on memory address)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this based on memory address, but honestly not sure.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do; the index of "fourthThree" is `3` - you already have that.  Similarly, in your first code, the index of the first 3 is `0` and the index of the last is `array.count-1`.  `3` is a value, so there is no specific "3" in the array; they are all the same.

Comment: Well I'm wondering if there is a way to tie the references together. Like if I perform some other operations, or pass these values into a function, and therefore I don't know that "fourthThree" is index 3, I just know that it is a 3 with some memory address. Is there any way to associate that with the fourth object in the "lotsOfThrees" array. Preferably with a library function. I basically want to know if there is any library function that would allow me to pass back array.last and distinguish it from array.first if they have the same value

Comment: Why are you needing this? What problem are you actually try to solve with this?

Comment: I'm attempting to implement a solution that will handle a sorted or unsorted array to solve the "Two-Sum" problem. I need to return different indices of the values when there are duplicates.

Comment: I don't see why you need to use `indexOf` for a solution to the two-sum problem

Comment: Well I have since found a faster solution, but then it got me thinking about how to identify these values based on index, so I figured I'd ask about it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *last* index of an element by reversing the array, then getting the index of the *first* occurrence. The last element's index in the original array is then (index of first occurrence in reversed array) - (size of array) - 1. Put it in an extension method for added fun.

```
extension Array<T> {   
    func lastIndex(of item: T) -> Int? {
        if let lastIndex = self.reverse().index(of: item) {
            return self.count() - lastIndex - 1
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `enumerated()` and `filter` to pair indices with the value you are looking for:

```
let lotsOfThrees = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
let threesAndIndices = lotsOfThrees.enumerated().filter { $1 == 3 }
print(threesAndIndices)
```

> ```
> [(offset: 0, element: 3), (offset: 1, element: 3), (offset: 2, element: 3), (offset: 3, element: 3), (offset: 4, element: 3), (offset: 5, element: 3), (offset: 6, element: 3)]
> ```

```
// find index of last three
print(threesAndIndices.last!.offset)
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
// find index of 4th three
print(threesAndIndices[4 - 1].offset)
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

---

You should check the size of the array and not assume that there is a last value like this:

```
let values = [1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1]
let threesAndIndices = values.enumerated().filter { $1 == 3 }

// find index of last three
if let last = threesAndIndices.last {
    print("index of last three is \(last.offset)")
} else {
    print("there are no threes")
}
```

> ```
> index of last three is 6
> ```

```
// find index of 4th three
let nth = 4
if nth > threesAndIndices.count {
    print("there aren't \(nth) threes")
} else {
    let index = threesAndIndices[nth - 1].offset
    print("the index of three #\(nth) is \(index)")
}
```

> ```
> there aren't 4 threes
> ```